# Mutate array as a property in Object

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on some homework and encounter some weird behavior ( to me ) about changing properties value in a object . Show in below code :

```js
    // let say I have a object 
    const a = {
      name:"origin",
      arr:["origin"],
    }

    // then I create another object and fill that object with props of "a"
    
    const b = {...a}
    
    // then doing some mutate with props of "b"
    
    b.name = "mutated";
    b.arr.push("mutated");
    
    
    // but it also change "arr" props of "a" (name is not change)
    
    console.log(a.name); // log "origin"
    console.log(a.arr);// log ["origin", "mutated"]
```

I don't understand why it also changed the props of `a` . Can anyone explain it for me ? Am I using the wrong technology here (`...`) ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object rest `{ ...someObj }` only creates a shallow copy of the `someObj`. The new object will be new, but if the old object property values happened to be objects themselves - like arrays or objects - then mutating *those* in either the new or the old object will be seen in both.

[image]

If you want a change to the `arr` not to change the original, make a copy explicitly, eg

```js
// let say I have a object 
const a = {
  name:"origin",
  arr:["origin"],
}

// then I create another object and fill that object with props of "a"

const b = {...a, arr: a.arr.slice() }
b.name = "mutated";
b.arr.push("mutated");

console.log(a.name); // log "origin"
console.log(a.arr);// log ["origin"]
```